# How to use temporary tables in SQL

Tags: sql

Please tell me how to make temporary tables in SQL.  I am new to this area.

Comment: btw @Atul.  If any of the answers below are the correct one, don't forget to click on the big tick next to the answer so the next person reading this knows the solution also.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE TABLE #Yaks (
YakID int,
YakName char(30) )

select name
from tempdb..sysobjects 
where name like '#yak%'

drop table #yaks
```

[Did a Google search and found this as the first hit.](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/temporary-tables)

Answer (score 0):

**Assuming T-SQL:**

```
DECLARE @ProductTotals TABLE
(
  ProductID int,
  Revenue money
)

INSERT INTO @ProductTotals (ProductID, Revenue)
  SELECT ProductID, SUM(UnitPrice * Quantity)
    FROM [Order Details]
    GROUP BY ProductID

UPDATE @ProductTotals
  SET Revenue = Revenue * 1.15
WHERE ProductID = 62

DELETE FROM @ProductTotals
WHERE ProductID = 60


SELECT TOP 5 *
FROM @ProductTotals
ORDER BY Revenue DESC
```

That is a **table variable**. There is also an **in-memory table** - instead of **DECLARE @ProductTotals** use **CREATE TABLE #ProductTotals**.

Use Table Variable for holding data during lifetime of SPROC/Function.

Use In Memory Tables for holding data over multiple SPROC's/child SPROC's. Needs to be explicitly dropped.

Comment: The #ProductTotals tables are **NOT** in-memory - they are persisted to disk. Also note: while #ProductTotals tables will participate in transactions, @ProductTotals (in-memory table variables) do not which might cause some surprises.

Comment: @marc_s yeah i can never think of the name of the # tables. what is it? is it "temporary tables". if so, what is are the @ one's called. good point about transactions too.

Comment: @ProductTotals = in-memory table variable; #ProductTotals = temporary table (on disk, for this connection only, gone after connection is closed); ##ProductTotal = global temporary table, visible to all connections, persistent

Comment: @marc_s. It's not true to assume table variables are any more in memory than temp tables are. Both create a table structure in tempdb and both will be held in memory if small enough. http://scarydba.wordpress.com/2009/10/13/table-variables-are-only-in-memory-fact-or-myth/

Comment: @Martin Smith: true - table variables are potentially in memory - if small enough, right? #temp and ##temp tables never are as far as I know

Comment: @marc - See page 97 here http://www.scribd.com/doc/24594811/Inside-Microsoft%C2%AE-SQL-Server%E2%84%A2-2005-T-SQL-Programming

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT columnNames INTO #temp FROM TableName    
SELECT * FROM #temp    
DROP TABLE #temp
```